# Create jpg using imagejpeg and saving it without showing it on the page

Tags: php, jpeg, imagejpeg

Right now I am using a php script (let's say the save-page) to create a jpeg and save it to the server. Although it all works, when opening the save-page, the jpeg is also shown, which I don't really want. I just want the jpeg to be created and saved to the desired destination. To be clear, the saving is already working. The is part of the script that I am using.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('*link to the base image*');

$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);
$font_path = 'interstate.ttf';

imagettftext($jpg_image, 14, 0, 44, 41, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);

// save jpg to widget folder
imagejpeg($jpg_image, 'widget/vehicle_1_' . $id . '.jpg');

//free up memory
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

How can I change the script so that it saves the jpg to the widget folder, but not show it on this page when activated? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply remove `imagejpeg($jpg_image);` and the header, and replace with `print('Image saved!');`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I tried to remove both before, but not at the same time.